# show icon in listview from database

Tags: android, database, image, listview

i have a listview that shows diferent data from my database. this works perfeclty. however i can only have 3 items in my list becouse i run out of memory since im loading the full images. this is the code i have now that is working, but gives out of memory when more then three list items are in the list.

```
  String[] from = new String[] { "NAME", "DATE", "WEIGHT", "IMAGE_PATH"};      
  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.date, R.id.weight, R.id.list_image};
  contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
     Mylistview.this, R.layout.list_row, null, from, to);
  setListAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

what i want to do is shrink the images to 72x72 before loading them in the list. Below is a code that is not working the way i want, but it gives you an idea of what i want :)

```
  list_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.list_image);


  String[] from = new String[] { "NAME", "DATE", "WEIGHT", "IMAGE_PATH"};      
  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.date, R.id.weight};
  contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
     Mylistview.this, R.layout.list_row, null, from, to);
  setListAdapter(contactAdapter); 

 String icon = "IMAGE_PATH"

  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(icon);        
  Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 72, 72, false);
  list_image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

i want the String icon to get the image path from "IMAGE_PATH" that is loaded from the database in the string array.

is there a way to do this, or do i need to find other ways to populate my listview with both images and small icons? perhaps when i take a picture i should save the image in two places. one real image and one icon and put the icon path to the database?

thank you

This is the code and the error code after doing what Vishva Patel helped with.

```
       BitmapScaler scaler = null;
try {
    scaler = new BitmapScaler(new File("IMAGE_PATH"), 72);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  list_image.setImageBitmap(scaler.getScaled());
```

---

```
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  start activity   ComponentInfo{se.xflash.myapp/se.xflash.myapp.myapp}:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{se.xflash.myapp/se.xflash.myapp.MyNames}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.xflash.myapp/se.xflash.myapp.MyNames}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1809)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at se.xflash.myapp.myapp.onCreate(myapp.java:45)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    ... 11 more
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at se.xflash.myapp.BitmapScaler.<init>(BitmapScaler.java:42)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at se.xflash.myapp.MyNames.onCreate(MyNames.java:56)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
 08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) The easiest solution would be to use the class mentioned in this blogpost BitmapScaler.java : http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/android-bitmap-scaling/ , it works excellently and solves the out of memory exception issue. All you have to do is provide the file where your image is saved as a parameter to the constructor along with the scaled width that you want (72 in your case). Here's the code you'd have to use in your specific case:

```
BitmapScaler scaler = new BitmapScaler(new File("IMAGE_PATH"), 72);
list_image.setImageBitmap(scaler.getScaled());
```

2.) Yes, one of the solutions would be to scale the bitmap when you take the picture and save it as icon-yourimagename.jpg along with your original image (if you need the original size image that you took)

3.) Use bm.recycle() once your have assigned bm to your list_image to ensure that the bitmaps are garbage collected and that some memory is freed. This MIGHT fix the memory error.

Comment: nice one, this realy looks interesting. however this gives me a null point expression. to make eclipse happy i must surround scaler with a try and catch and make scaler = null. and thats not working :)      BitmapScaler scaler = null;
 try {
  scaler = new BitmapScaler(new File("IMAGE_PATH"), 72);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
      list_image.setImageBitmap(scaler.getScaled());

Comment: Wait, what line of code throws a NullPointerException, can you copy and paste the content of the line that throws the null point exception? And of course, you have to surround that code with a try catch because you are creating a new File() which might throw an IOException if that file doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, what I'd meant was can you post the exact line of code that's throwing the nullpointerexception. You can find out this line by clicking this message in the error log in eclipse. PLEASE COPY PASTE THE CONTENT OF THAT LINE OF CODE :  08-08 22:23:15.973: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):    at se.xflash.myapp.BitmapScaler.<init>(BitmapScaler.java:42)

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful, im new to this but im sure you have figured that out :) that line does not say much. only is.close();

Comment: What i did was that i copied the BitmapScaler.java from the blog you showed me, and made a new class file. i have not changed anything in it. then i tried with the code you gave me.

Comment: We all start out new at some point :) Oh, I know why it's throwing the nullpointerexception. Can you tell me what the value of "IMAGE_PATH" is?

Comment: the image path is the String to the filepath on the SD card. /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/IMG_20120808_025738. i tried to hardcode that path but it did not work either. is there a problem with converting from a string to bitmap?

Comment: the problem is that the filepath isn't valid, and hence the File is not being created which makes the FileInputStream created from this file null (hence the null pointer exception). Are you sure that that's the filepath being used? Please use Log or Toast the value of "IMAGE_PATH". Shouldn't the filepath be "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/IMG_20120808_025738.jpg"? i.e isn't the filepath missing the file extension?

Comment: yea its a jpg and its the correct file path, becouse i get the image to load in the listview if you read in my first example in original post. however that loads the full image and gives out of memory when more then three list items are in the list. (three diferent images). the jpg extension is in the database. i just forgot to write it here on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Oh, I just saw this. In your code you declare BitmapScaler scaler = null. Remove this declaration and just declare BitmapScaler scaler = new BitmapScaler(new File("IMAGE_PATH"), 72); and move the list_image.setImageBitmap(scaler.getScaled()); into the 'try' block of the code: i.e right below BitmapScaler scaler = .. ;

Comment: if i hardcode the filepath it gets send to the image scaler, but then gives a NPE when trying to set the imageview. list_image.setImageBitmap(scaler.getScaled()); if i set the scaler to "IMAGE_PATH" the string "IMAGE_PATH" is send to bitmapScaler.java, it dosnt read the path from the database. however. even if i would get the path from the database, it crashes on trying to set the image view :) this was tricky haha

Comment: Oh, the string "IMAGE_PATH" shouldn't be sent to the bitmapScaler, the actual filepath is what's needed (but I guess you know that). The problem ultimately is that the fileinputstream isn't being created and is hence null. The only reason why it wouldn't be created is due to a non-existent file or a malformed filepath. So my advice would be to debug your code and figure out where this arrangement gets distorted

Comment: yea i must look deeper into this :) thank you so much for trying to help me! its very much apreciated.

Comment: @user1512762 I wouldn't say this normally but seeing as you are new to this site, could you accept my answer? You can do so by clicking the green tick mark on the upper left hand side of this answer (it's below the up vote and down vote buttons). Cheers! Do let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: i was planing on doing that :)

Comment: btw, this code String sdf = scaler.getScaled().toString(); Log.e("sdf", sdf); outputs in LogCat Bitmap@414e3980 just before trying to set the imageview. dosnt that mean something is returned?